# Writable /vendor directory? Simple data storage

Tags: symfony

I'm creating symfony2 bundle which helps making request to some API.

When user not pass the token value (required in request) then I try to acquire this token and save it in my bundle directory (to read it later). But this path is not writable.

How can I handle simple data storage? Is my approach good or I miss something?

Should my bundle save such values in /vendor directory?

@edit: Asking user to make the directory writable is IMO bad solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `/vendor` should not be writable by your application. You'll likely overwrite anything you save to `/vendor` the next time you perform a `composer update` or `composer install`.

It sounds like what you need is a persistent piece of configuration information that's outside the scope of your `parameters.yml` or `config.yml` (since you want to change it at runtime). Saving into a cache directory doesn't sound appropriate, so you're going to want to store it in some persistent location; probably your database, or a persistent key in redis or other similar storage.

If a cache directory is sufficient, though, you can get the location from the container's `kernel.cache_dir` parameter; but that will be erased each time the cache is cleared..

Comment: I just thought about cache directory and it's OK for this purpose. Later I will provide the interface to change the storage, maybe someone will need to store it in db like you said